# How to run the hbfsy command with gulp?

Tags: backbone.js, package.json

I am using browserify to create a bundle.js to bundle all my backbone js views,collections and models into one.

I am using the following command:

```
browserify -t [hbsfy -e html,htm,hbs] .scripts/app.js > bundle.js
```

*I can't seem to get it to work via a gulp command*

```
 gulp.task('browserify', function() {
        return browserify('./app/scripts/app.js')
                .bundle()
                .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
                .pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

I also have less files which i need to compile.

Error i get

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself

This is how i am building handlebars in my gulp file:

```
    process.env.BROWSERIFYSHIM_DIAGNOSTICS=1;

var hbsfy = require('hbsfy').configure({
  extensions: ['html','hbs','htm']
});

gulp.task('browserify', function(){
    return browserify({
      transform: [hbsfy, 'node-lessify','browserify-shim'],
            entries: ['./app/scripts/app.js']
        })
        .bundle()

        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```